# How to make wkhtmltopdf behave the same on both servers?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I've got two identical copies of wkhtmltopdf on two Linux servers--one a development server and the other a production server.  (I know the wkhtmltopdf's are identical because I copied from one server to the other.)

When I feed a certain URL to wkhtmltopdf on the dev server, the resulting PDF looks perfect.  When I feed the identical URL to wkhtmltopdf on the production server, the resulting PDF has certain div's scaled to the wrong size, and certain elements positioned incorrectly.

My assumption is that there must be certain libraries used by wkhtmltopdf which differ on the two servers.  However, I haven't been able to find a comprehensive list of wkhtmltopdf's dependencies.  The skimpy docs say to install X11, gcc and openssl, all of which I've done via yum install.

Any thoughts about what might cause different behavior using identical URL arguments and identical binaries?

Comment: I think this may be fixed.  Through random googling, found someone who suggested package "a2ps" might be relevant.  Did a "yum install a2ps" and the problem went away.

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows. I parse a very simple html file through wkhtmltopdf no fancy arguments just "wkhtmltopdf.exe test.html test.pdf" it gives two different results on two different machines? Did you find out what the root cause of the problem was?